# In php how to assign specific array key to main array

Tags: php, arrays

I got the below o/p

```
$test1=["12","54","87","98"];
$test2=["1","5","8","9"];
```

In that how can i connect a above two variable in to one variable like below

1 is key of 12,
5 is key of 54,
8 is key of 87,
9 is key of 98,

Comment: use `array_combine()`.

Comment: [`array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Thank u dear, it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$test1=["12","54","87","98"];

$test2=["1","5","8","9"];

$a = array_combine($test2, $test1);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($a);

exit;
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: thank u dear, its working good

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$test1=["12","54","87","98"];
$test2=["1","5","8","9"];


$new_array = array();

$i = 0;
foreach( $test2 as $key=> $value )
{
    $new_array[$value] = $test1[$i];
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: array_combine is best dear

Comment: I think so because its built in function.@KarnaGowtham

Comment: ok ok dear, i find out the solution

Comment: You are welcome @KarnaGowtham